# VENDOR_NOTIFICATION is not sent for Stacked Webapps

Tags: billing

**Question**: When Vendor Notifications are triggered?

**Reference Ticket**: https://appdirect.jira.com/browse/CIM-245

Answer (score 0):

Vendor Notification is triggered only in below cases:

1. EventType is SUBSCRIPTION_ORDER and SendNotification flag is true for event and partner is FICO.
   Or
2. ProductType is WEB_APP_MANUAL_SETUP and CustomIntegration is not SYMANTEC_EV_CLOUD.

Primary use of VENDOR_NOTIFICATION template is to send the email to email address set by Developer/ISV on the ProductType.WEB_APP_MANUAL_SETUP's Edit Integration section. Since the product has no integration to developer endpoints, the developer relies on email to notify them of subscription operations (create, change, cancel, suspend, etc) that they need to process on their side.

VENDOR_NOTIFICATION template for integrated apps (WEB_APP, STACKED_WEB_APP) would be redundant and could be conflicting - their systems (endpoints) are already being notified in real-time of subscription events through the integration web-hooks.